# Tour options in Doha

Tags: transit, tours, guides, qatar, doha

I have a 17hr transit in Doha and am getting a free hotel, thanks to Qatar Airways. What are the best tour options for tours that will pick me up at/near the hotel? I am staying at Oryx Rotana Doha. I have also thought about finding a couple of places to visit and just getting a taxi or bus there. Does anyone have any advice? I arrive in Doha at 14:50. Also, what about immigration? How long will it take me to get out of the airport? I qualify for a visa-free entry.

Comment: You can use Qatar+ service of Qatar airways to book a tour as well. Those are not the only tours obviously but since those will be more tailored towards airline customers on a short transit time.

Comment: I think there won't be a definitive answer to this because ultimately it would boil down to your preference but please have a look at [Doha City Guide](https://www.qatarairways.com/en/destinations/flights-to-doha/doha-city-guide.html) and [Doha City Tour](https://www.qatarairways.com/en/offers/doha-city-tour.html)

Answer (score 1):

Qatar Airways provides multiple tours in a day and they suggest tours based on your arrival and departure times. You can take a look at the [official website](https://www.qatarairways.com/en-de/offers/doha-city-tour.html). I, myself, took a tour last year and it was decent.

However, the tour was cut short due to very long immigration queues and We had to wait for around 90 minutes. The tour agency tried to talk to the immigration authorities for faster immigration clearance but the request was denied.